# Is there a reason why restarting lightdm caused the device to shutdown?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, display-manager

Each time I have had to restart lightdm on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS via the commands `/etc/init.d/lightdm restart` or `service lightdm restart`, it would simply restart lightdm display manager. This time however it shutdown the device completely. Is there a way to find out why this may have happened?

Comment: Did this problem happen only once or does it happen all the time now ?

Comment: @HackToHell - So far just the one time however would like to know why